# 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot

I am trying to update the data using spring boot and angular, but whenever i try to update the data i got this error  'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is my spring controller and angular service.

I tried other solutions from stackoverflow but it doesn't work
please tell me what i am doing wrong here..

**InfoController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class InfoController {

@Autowired
private InfoDAO infoDAO;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")

@PutMapping("/infos/{id}")
public List<Info> updateStudent(@RequestBody Info info, @PathVariable int id) {

    List<Info> information = infoDAO.getbyID(id);

    System.out.println("this is id");

    info.setId(id);

    infoDAO.update(info);

    // info1.update(info1);

    return information;
}

  }
```

**InfoDAO.java**

```
List<Info> getbyID(int id);
boolean update(Info info);
```

**InfoDAOImpl.java**

```
public class InfoDAOImpl implements InfoDAO {

@PersistenceContext
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public List<Info> getbyID(int id) {
    String query = "FROM Info WHERE id = :id";
    return em
                .createQuery(query,Info.class)
                .setParameter("id",id)  
                .getResultList();
 }

public boolean update(Info info) {
    try {           
        em
                    .merge(info);
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {       
        return false;
    }                   
}
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired DataSource dataSource;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
     http.
     cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())
    .and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/Signup").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), customUserDetailService));
}

@Bean   
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type", "xsrfheadername","xsrfcookiename"
    ,"X-Requested-With","XSRF-TOKEN","Accept", "x-xsrf-token","withcredentials","x-csrftoken"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("custom-header1", "custom-header2"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
    return source; 
}
```

**Web.service.ts**

```
export class WebService {

constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8083/student';

editPlan(data: Student, id:any): Observable<any> {
    const url = `/infos/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.put(this.serverUrl + url, data);
}

getWebPlanInfo(): Observable<any> {
    const url = '/plan/info';
    return this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl + url);
}

}
```

Comment: Remove this line      `cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())` and check.

Comment: @gnana jeyam95 again i got the same problem where insert was working fine but edit and delete was blocked by CORS policy. Finally your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: cool. Did u understand the issue..?

Comment: no i don't understand how can it possible one request worked and other didn't.

Comment: @gnana jeyam95 You should post it as answer cause i don't find solution on my issue anywhere.

Comment: Due to this line `request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())` it allows the request type for specific methods like GET but not for every methods.

Comment: Sure I will add this as an answer wait.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219030/discussion-between-gnana-jeyam95-and-vidy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is with this Line `cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())`.

If you remove this line it will work.

**But how ?** That is because your `@Bean` method `corsConfigurationSource` will be loaded by spring container during the runtime and it will create the Bean for this.

By adding this line `cors().configurationSource(request -> new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues())` it overrides the Bean `corsConfigurationSource`.

This method `applyPermitDefaultValues()` in `CorsConfiguration` class will allow `GET`, `POST`, `HEAD` request methods by default. Due to this your `PUT/DELETE` method is not working.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.java#L428 [image]

Answer (score 2):

In your spring security configuration use the following, so that the `corsconfiguration` bean that you are creating is automatically taken up by spring instead of the configuration that you provided in the http bean itself.In your configuration you were using the new operator to create an instance yourself manually rather than leaving it to spring to autowire the `corsconfiguration` bean that you provided below . So try like :

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
     http.
     cors().and().csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()                                                                
            .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/login").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/Signup").hasRole("USER")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), customUserDetailService));
}


@Bean   
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
    configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("custom-header1", "custom-header2"));
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration); 
    return source; 
}
```

In theory, if you have setup everything right spring security should automatically add the response headers like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to your response. Official [spring secutiy doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#cors)  official [cors](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework#spring-boot-integration) [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-cors)

Comment: Works like a charm!